# Installing odbc_connect() in php Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: php, macos, odbc, osx-mavericks

I have a server that needs to have an odbc connection from a PHP web server in the built in Mac OS X apache web server to a data source on the same machine.  When I run the `odbc_connect()` command (with proper arguments) it gives me an error saying unknown command.  I believe the problem is that I don't have PHP libraries for odbc installed.  Does anybody have instructions on how to get `odbc_connect()` to work from the built in apache server on Mac OS X?

Thanks

Comment: either you don't have the libraries, or they're not enable, or they're misconfigured.

Comment: well how do I find which one of those is the issue and then, how do I fix?

Comment: if it's done as a module, you'd probably have something like `php_odbc.so` on your system somewhere. if it's not available as a module and has to be compiled into php, then you'd have to recompile php or find a copy that already has odbc compiled in. start by rummaging around in your php.ini files and see if there's anything odbc-related that's commented out.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095942/problems-compile-phalcon-on-osx-10-9/25100138#25100138